# Chakra UI icon not positioned inside Input

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm trying to position an icon correctly in the middle of an input, where that input has `size="xs"`. However, all my attempts have failed, and the icon keeps being positioned too low/down. I've also tried using `IconButton` instead of a regular icon but that didn't work either.

[image]

```
import { Input, InputGroup, InputLeftElement } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { SearchIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons"

// ...

    <InputGroup>
      <InputLeftElement
        pointerEvents="none"
        children={<SearchIcon color="gray.300"/>}
        size="xs"
        />
      <Input
        variant="outline"
        size="xs"
        placeholder={``}
      />
    </InputGroup>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the codesandbox. Note that in this codesandbox, the icon is actually above the middle of Input (which is still wrong), instead of below as on my local machine.

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-bartik-5ifsd?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @MajidMohammadi https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-bartik-5ifsd?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve the problem by adding `className` to `chakra` components and editing styles:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <InputGroup>
      <InputLeftElement
        className="InputLeft"
        pointerEvents="none"
        children={<SearchIcon className="SearchIcon" color="gray.300" />}
        size="xs"
      />
      <Input className="Input" variant="outline" size="xs" placeholder={``} />
    </InputGroup>
  );
}
```

And Here's the styles:

```
.InputLeft {
  top: 3px !important;
  left: 3px !important;
}
.Input {
  padding-left: 24px !important;
}
```

If in your local, the icon is below the input. You can change the `top` to `bottom` in  `InputLeft`  class.

Here's the updated `codesandbox` :

[image: Edit sleepy-mayer-71qmj]

Comment: That worked for me in the sandbox but not on my local machine. I believe I need a proper/dynamic solution instead of a hardcoded one. Image after applying this CSS and changing `top` to `bottom` in it: https://ibb.co/Dg073xs

Comment: Maybe the input gives other styles which impress the input's style. Have you applied other styles?

Comment: You should change the left , top or bottom values to icon set in the correct position.

Comment: That will work on my machine, but what happens when someone is using another device with a small screen and the size of the page etc shrinks? I'm not sure that hardcoding a value will work across all devices?

Comment: Actually for responsive styles you should use media screens to support all displays.

Comment: In this scenario which you mentioned in the answer, I thought that your aim is just solve the problem and it doesn't matter component in which device will be load.

Comment: It looks like this is a bug in Chakra, so I will award you the correct answer, since your way is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is solvable without CSS. You just have to add the size attribute to the InputGroup as well.

See the updated code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-frost-do7u7r).

```
     <InputGroup size="xs">
        <InputLeftElement
          pointerEvents="none"
          children={<SearchIcon color="gray.300" />}
          size="xs"
        />
        <Input variant="outline" size="xs" placeholder={``} />
      </InputGroup>
```